# What can be said about these graph in regards to correlation?

Tags: plot, statistics, plotly

I am (desperately) trying to generate a few graphs based on some data that I know has a correlation value of over 0.50 and I get these 2 graphs.

Needless to say, I am no statistician nor have I played with this subject before.

Here are the 2 graphs that I get:

[image: Graph 1]

[image: Graph 2]

What can be said about the 2 graphs individually? I am super confused by the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hard to say without knowing the full scope and context of your data. Few remarks;

1. there is some uper limit to the first graph above which all data points are considered to be 'out of range' (can't be 40 years with a company if I'm 30 years old.)
2. pay attention to [simpsons paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) and make sure you have the right segmentation of your data (and check it).
3. 2nd graph: if you only have values of 3 and 4 on the y-axis there is no use of plotting the grids and values for 3.2 etc. (it implies some significance/accuracy that's not there)
4. 2nd graph: seems there is some 'rule' that says you need rating of 4 to get certain % of salary raise.

but again, more (business) context and info on the data is needed to be able to help you out more.